# Why count(1) in hive inconsistent with the data insert by spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

In hive 2.3.6, I create a TEST_TABLE with single column

```
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 2.3.6)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 2.3.6)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
Beeline version 2.3.6 by Apache Hive
0: jdbc:hive2://SOMEHOST:10000> CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . > DUMMY VARCHAR(1)
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . > ) STORED AS ORC;
No rows affected (0.14 seconds)
```

Then I went to spark-shell(2.4.4) and insert single line into this table.

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.4
      /_/
         
Using Scala version 2.11.12 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_141)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val a = Seq( Tuple1.apply("X") )
a: Seq[(String,)] = List((X,))

scala> val b = spark.createDataFrame(a)
b: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: string]

scala> b.write.insertInto("TEST_TABLE")
```

In hive, it could be read

```
0: jdbc:hive2://SOMEHOST:10000> SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE;
+-------------------+
| test_table.dummy  |
+-------------------+
| X                 |
+-------------------+
1 row selected (0.138 seconds)
```

But COUNT NOT be count

```
0: jdbc:hive2://SOMEHOST:10000> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TEST_TABLE;
+------+
| _c0  |
+------+
| 0    |
+------+
1 row selected (0.24 seconds)
```

although it could be count correctly in spark

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TEST_TABLE").show
+--------+                                                                      
|count(1)|
+--------+
|       1|
+--------+
```

Comment: This might be because your hive and spark are installed with 2 different metastore_db. Just check for confirmation. Also check is changed done using hive are accessible on spark or not.

Comment: The metastore is one. Any changes made in Hive (eg. If I insert the single row in beeline like the example above) CAN BE read by Spark correctly.